# What happens if a translated/translating character is pregnant?

Tags: the-strange

A. If a character is pregnant in her homeworld, and then translates as a different species...:

1. ... is she still pregnant in the recursion?
2. ...and spends enough time in the recursion for birth, is the child born in the recursion? Is the child of the mother's new (temporary) species? Is the child considered a native of the recursion?
3. ...then returns before birth, is the child affected? (Specific question from a player was, will the child be quickened?)

B. Can a character become pregnant while translated as a different species?

1. Is she still pregnant when she returns to her homeworld (or translates to another recursion)?
2. Will the child be of the then-current species (natural or translated) when born?

The player apparently worried about this more than I did (I didn't tell her my plans) - she took the last couple of months of the pregnancy off from translating, stayed on Earth, and had the kid... then, about 3 months later, translated **with the child**.  So, the kid is quickened, regardless!

But still, the question remains: what consequences does translating have for a pregnant character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.

1. I would say yes, if the translated character is of a species and gender that can be pregnant. If not, the pregnancy is suspended until she translates to a recursion where she can be pregnant.
2. Yes. The child is of the same species as the mother at the time of birth. The child is a quickened native of the recursion.
3. I would say the child would be quickened.

B.

1. Yes, with the caveats from A1 above.
2. Yes, as A2 above.

Comment: Is this just your own house rule, or does it have basis in a published source? And if it's your own house rule, what is your experience of its consequences and function in play?